# Safari - IPhone - auto-changing scale of website

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, safari

There is some problem with a website on safari (iphone).
Can you suggest why is such metamorphosis occurs?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbaiu.jpg

On the other devices or desktop browsers there is no such problem.

Comment: Without being able to see the code, I would assume it has something to do with a JavaScript event handler of some sort. CSS and HTML would just be static unless you have some animations/transitions going on.

Comment: Does it happen on page load? If so, it might be related to some images loading. Apart from this, do you have any CSS transitions in your code?

Comment: Leander Rodrigues, can you show me how to do that with javascript?

Comment: To see the page shrink browser to narrow size and reload page https://belturizm.by/order.html?id=225859883086@805

Comment: http://joxi.net/Vm6QkZ6U43n4br